# how to create an autorelease object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsautoreleasepool

Is this method create an autorelease object?

```
- (instancetype)autoreleasePerson {
    return [[Person alloc] init];
}
```

I created an **Command Line Tool Project** to test this:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        {
            [Person autoreleasePerson];
            
        }
        NSLog(@"did out scope");
        
        NSLog(@"will out autoreleasepool");
    }
    NSLog(@"did out autoreleasepool");
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
2022-02-04 23:22:23.224298+0800 MyTest[8921:4007144] did out scope
2022-02-04 23:22:23.224771+0800 MyTest[8921:4007144] will out autoreleasepool
2022-02-04 23:22:23.224876+0800 MyTest[8921:4007144] -[Person dealloc]
2022-02-04 23:22:23.224948+0800 MyTest[8921:4007144] did out autoreleasepool
```

The person instance will dealloc when the autoreleasepool drains!

But when I use the same Person class in **my iOS APP project**:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    {
        [Person autoreleasePerson];
    }
    NSLog(@"out scope");
}
```

The output is:

```
2022-02-04 23:28:13.992969+0800 MyAppTest[9023:4011490] -[Person dealloc] <Person: 0x600001fe8ff0>
2022-02-04 23:28:13.993075+0800 MyAppTest[9023:4011490] out scope
```

The person instance released once out of scope!

Why is this so?

Comment: Thats the point of autoreleasepools. See the docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047

Consider it an own scope where elements can live longer than their scope. For the other snippet its logical because the retain count is 0 at the end of the scope, so ARC will cause to dealloc. This has a longer history from pre-ARC times, where you had to manually trigger release (or use those autorelease helpers to improve performance).

Comment: Interesting... I'd expect not. At minimum both should match. Is it the same if you assign it to a variable in the Command Line Tool? Is it the same if you move the call to a subfunciton?

Comment: @battlmonstr Yes, it`s the same

Answer (score 0):

It looks like on macOS the default behaviour is to autorelease return values, except for cases where the method name starts with "new", "init" or "copy":

```
+ (Person *)createPerson {
    return [Person new]; // autorelease & return
}
+ (Person *)newPerson {
    return [Person new]; // direct return
}
```

To control this behaviour apply a compiler attribute:

```
+ (Person *)createPerson __attribute__((ns_returns_retained)) {
    return [Person new]; // direct return
}
+ (Person *)newPerson __attribute__((ns_returns_not_retained)) {
    return [Person new]; // autorelease & return
}
```

To check whether a call to objc_autoreleaseReturnValue was added by the compiler, enable Debug -> Debug Workflow -> Always Show Disassembly,
and put a breakpoint inside these methods on return lines. A call to objc_autoreleaseReturnValue should be visible then:

[image]

[See ARC reference - Retained return values](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#retained-return-values)

Comment: Thank you!   I put a breakpoint inside the dealloc method of Person class，and the instance was released by the function ```libobjc.A.dylib`objc_unsafeClaimAutoreleasedReturnValue:```. I also found this from the doc you mentioned above:**There are no additional semantics enforced in the definition of such a method; it merely enables optimizations in callers**。So I think this is because apple has done some optimization. Am I right?

Comment: In theory - yes. If it somehow knows that the method can be inlined, it can remove this call. If you want to dig deeper - you could look into the clang source code (ARC-related optimizations). It is open source.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the results are valid. You should never assume that there is an autorelease in ARC. See the section "[Unretained return values](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#unretained-return-values)" in the ARC specification:

> A method or function which returns a retainable object type but does
> not return a retained value must ensure that the object is still valid
> across the return boundary.
>
> When returning from such a function or method, ARC retains the value
> at the point of evaluation of the return statement, then leaves all
> local scopes, and then balances out the retain while ensuring that the
> value lives across the call boundary. **In the worst case, this may
> involve an autorelease, but callers must not assume that the value is
> actually in the autorelease pool.**

So maybe it's autoreleased, and maybe not (i.e. maybe ARC optimizes it out).

Here, ARC will call [`objc_autoreleaseReturnValue()`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#arc-runtime-objc-autoreleasereturnvalue) when returning from `autoreleasePerson`, because `+alloc` returns a retained reference, but `autoreleasePerson` returns a non-retained reference. What `objc_autoreleaseReturnValue()` does is check to see if the result of the return will be passed to `objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue()` in the calling function frame. If so, it can skip both the autorelease in the called function, and the retain in the calling function (since they "cancel out"), and hand off ownership directly into a retained reference in the calling function.

[`objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue()`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#arc-runtime-objc-retainautoreleasedreturnvalue) is called when ARC will retain the result of a function call. Now, I don't know why in this case calling `[Person autoreleasePerson];` will involve a retain of the result, since the result is unused. Perhaps the compiler is treating it as `Person temp = [Person autoreleasePerson];`, and thus retains and then releases it. This may seem unnecessary, but it is valid for ARC to do it this way. And if ARC does happen to treat it this way internally, then the optimization described above can skip both the autorelease and retain, and it will be simply released in the calling function. Maybe it's doing this in one of your cases and not the other. Who knows why? But my point is that both are valid.

See [this article](https://www.galloway.me.uk/2012/02/how-does-objc_retainautoreleasedreturnvalue-work/) for a more detailed explanation.